# xml onClick does not work after orientation change

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton, screen-orientation

My onClick in xml does not work after orientation change. I read many posts about onClickListerners not working which are created in the onCreate() method but that is not the case.

**This is my xml:**

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onSearchClick"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />
```

**In code:**

```
public void onSearchClick(View v){
    newSearch();
}
```

It worked fine before orientation change but not after. What could be the problem?

Comment: Post Activity code...

Comment: @dieter_h what could be interesting?

Comment: I just made a sample app, with a simple button and defined the click in the xml and it works for me in both portrait and landscape. Interesting.

Comment: in your manifest do you have something like this: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Comment: No, there is no configchange

Comment: Could the problem be that the method is in a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set on click listner in onCreate method:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                newSearch();
            }
        });
}
```

Remove: `android:onClick="onSearchClick"`

Comment: Any ideas as to why it doesn't work when the click method is defined in the xml? Since that what's the question is about. Yours is a workaround that will work.

Comment: Did you have 2 layouts `res/layout-land` and r`es/layout-port`?